# How to make a 2d Array in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qlabel

Hi my question is simple, I just asked in the QT Forums but nobody answer to me.

I just wanted to make a 2D array of a QLabel, can somebody help me, All I read about it, they use a dynamic vector, something like this:

```
<QVector <Data_Type>>
```

I can't use that (My project don't have to use that yet, crap specifications I know), so I have to use a 2D like in C++ or C.
    EDIT: I have the 2D Array but dont know how to show it, All I have is this, and don't give me errors:

```
    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget;
    QLabel **maze;
    maze= new QLabel*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        maze[i]= new QLabel[y];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
            maze[i][j].setPixmap(test);
            maze[i][j].move(i*60,j*60);
        }
    }
    mainWidget->show();
           setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
```

Now I just want to show the images, once I run the project, no images appear, is the Widget thing right? How to show in the Main Window? I need a 2D Widget too?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the x and y are number of rows and columns, correspondingly, you can simply do this trick:

```
[..]
QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
        label->setPixmap("Path_Of_The_Image");
        grid.addWidget(label, i, j);
    }
}
[..]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm already doing that, I'm trying to set positions with the grid, but the Size of the QLabel(The 2D array) is  dynamic, I don't know the real size. So I tried to set a standard position and margin around the window for this Dynamic Array(Using the QGridLayout obviously), but every time I change it, the spaces between the QLabel change (Horizontal and Vertical Spaces), even if I set the space between them to zero. It's possible to use a 2D Array? Nobody tried before?

Comment: @vitaR, please show what you want to do. Any mockup?

Comment: I'm Making a Maze. Im reading a Maze from a .txt File, The project says, the size of rows ans colums can be between 5 and 15. It's not a game at all, you have two characters, a cat and a mouse, and they have to find a path to the exit, you make the logic code to do this, then you just show the process in the window, using images (You dont have to press any key, just Reload the Window). I'm very new on QT, so I just want to know simple things to do it. So like I said, I tried with QGridLayout, but the space between them, the position of this layout and margins, is not letting me to do things.

Comment: Hi vitaR, I think you are using the wrong tools for the job. QLabels are not suited for displaying maze components. Use QML/Qt Quick instead: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsensors-maze-example.html